# Is there a maximum length in Codeigniter falshdata?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, error-handling

The reason why I'm asking that is I'm becoming mad about a small stupid message I'd like to pass to the next view. So if I do :

```
if(!$this->paypal_pro->APICallSuccessful($PayPalResult['ACK']))
        {
            var_dump($PayPalResult['ERRORS']);
            $message=array();
            foreach ($PayPalResult['ERRORS'] as $row => $error){
                // $message['flashError'][$row]['L_SHORTMESSAGE'] = $error['L_SHORTMESSAGE'];
                $message['flashError'][$row]['test'] = "The Session class permits you maintain a user's";
                // $message['flashError'][$row]['L_ERRORCODE'] = $error['L_ERRORCODE'];
                // $message['flashError'][$row]['L_LONGMESSAGE'] = $error['L_LONGMESSAGE'];
            }
            // print_r($message);
            $this->session->set_flashdata($message);

            redirect('main/Form');
        }
```

It works great, but if I do :

```
    if(!$this->paypal_pro->APICallSuccessful($PayPalResult['ACK']))
    {
        var_dump($PayPalResult['ERRORS']);
        $message=array();
        foreach ($PayPalResult['ERRORS'] as $row => $error){
            // $message['flashError'][$row]['L_SHORTMESSAGE'] = $error['L_SHORTMESSAGE'];
            $message['flashError'][$row]['test'] = "The Session class permits you maintain a user's  and track their activity while";
            // $message['flashError'][$row]['L_ERRORCODE'] = $error['L_ERRORCODE'];
            // $message['flashError'][$row]['L_LONGMESSAGE'] = $error['L_LONGMESSAGE'];
        }
        // print_r($message);
        $this->session->set_flashdata($message);

        redirect('main/Form');
    }
```

It doesn't work.

I'm showing the falshdata here, in main/form :

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('flashError')):?>
        <div class='flashError'>
    <?php   
        print_r($this->session->flashdata('flashError'));
    ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif?>
```

You can guess I'm trying to pull the error messages of Payal to the view for my errors Handling.
Thanks

Comment: Nope, I've looked at it over and over and I just can't see the difference between the two code samples. Is it like a [magic eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Eye) or something? I could never do those things... *Edit* oh wait I see it now. It's just an arbitrary data difference. So my guess is that the answer to the question is "No, the problem probably resides somewhere around that single quote." - although why this would cause a problem based on the above code I have no idea.

Comment: well yeah the difference is just about few letters in the $message['flashError'][$row]['test'] variable. and it obviously comes from here since when I have a small variable it works and when its more than around 20 chars, It doesn't work ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had lots of issues with sessions (which are essentially [cookies by default](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) in Codeigniter unless you store in the db). The session size (or cookie size) depends on the browser but I think the norm is around 3k - so won't handle what you are proposing to do.

I wasn't so sure about storing the session details in the db, so added the [native sessions library](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session) and it has been much easier (and less buggy). You can still use the CI flashdata feature with this library (as well as set session data like $this->session->set_userdata('foo', $foo), but it allows you to use sessions just like you were using native PHP i.e. you can print_r($_SESSION) - which I don't think you can do with default session features in CI.

Here's a post with some more information: [CodeIgniter sessions vs PHP sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005552/codeigniter-sessions-vs-php-sessions)

Answer (score 2):

In Codeigniter, the general size of the whole session data is limited, yes. That includes the flash messages as well.

This is because by default it works with cookies and cookies are of limited size.

The easy way to prevent that is to use database based sessions or one of the PHP native session adapters.

Comment: yeah but my session isn't that big, I may have something like 20 session vriables, all contening a small amount of information. Is there native databse based sessions in CI ?

Comment: Yes you can use the session configuration to enable database based sessions. See the Codeiginiter userguide about sessions, http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html