# Alternative way display error message in codeigniter when string length is maximum

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code snippet in **codeigniter**

```
if ($val_err_msg != '') {

$this->session->set_flashdata ( 'error',$val_err_msg);
redirect('Page');
                }
```

Where the length of string `$val_err_msg` is `13167`.

So the problem is the message is not getting displayed in the Page,

I have gone through [CodeIgniter sessions vs PHP sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005552/codeigniter-sessions-vs-php-sessions)
, [Is there a maximum length in Codeigniter falshdata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820345/is-there-a-maximum-length-in-codeigniter-falshdata)
 but i didn't got the solution how to display the message if the string length exceeds the limit in flash data.

Is there any other alternative way to display the message

Answer (score -2):

Change your config.php:

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
```

TO

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: It is useful to explain how exactly will that help the user. Especially when suggesting that the user should make such a great change as this method also comes with having to create a db table as per the docs.