# Codeigniter session cookie is secure or not?

Tags: security, codeigniter, session, cookies

I'm wondering about how a user can be manipulate his cookie.

As i know CI can know that (because the relation cookie_value/unique_key at the end of the cookie) and when happens CI renew the cookie.

And he log this:

> The session cookie data did not match what was expected. This could be
>   a possible hacking attempt

The point is, some people tell about using native php session to store login data but the risk of theft is the same (and maybe less for CI cookie). The only difference i can see is user can see what data is stored in CI cookie session.

So CI session cookie is secure or not ?
Or why it is less secure than native php session ?

I care to keep the load charge down too for a high traffic website.

Sorry for my poor english..

**Edit to explain CI session validation:**

Assuming you **do not want store sensible data**, the session cookie will be not encrypted and not saved in database.

Accordingly to CI 2.1.3 Session library, method `CI_Session::sess_read()` declared at line 135 and method `CI_Session::ses_write()` at line 235.

**When CI create the cookie, it put this data**

```
[array]
(
     'session_id'    => random hash,
     'ip_address'    => 'string - user IP address',
     'user_agent'    => 'string - user agent data',
     'last_activity' => timestamp
)
```

it serialize this array and put an md5 hash(from serialized data and the encryption key provided in config) at the end.

```
// if encryption is not used, we provide an md5 hash to prevent userside tampering
$cookie_data = $cookie_data.md5($cookie_data.$this->encryption_key);
```

**So when the session library will be initialized from the next http request to CI**

It will do and ask itself that:

1. separe `data` and `hash` from the session cookie
2. md5 `hash` is it equal to `md5( data + encryption_key )` ?
3. Does `data` can be unserialized ?
4. All the minimal data is it here ?
5. this session is it expired ?
6. Does IP match ?
7. Does USER AGENT match ?

If any of these answers is NO, CI session will be destroy and reset.

So tell me please, the relative risk in addition to PHP native session for this case.

Comment: What do you mean by secure cookie ? Did you subverted authorization mechanisms by changig cookie value ? No, so it is secure? Did browser allow you to change cookie ? Yes. Does it mean that cookie is not secure ?

Comment: I udpdated my question..

Comment: CI session is too safe if you use database to store your session data.

Comment: Ok but exclude database solution.

Comment: Without database solution it's less safe but still now you can use encryption.

Comment: Without encryption too, i just do not want my user can editing his cookie but keeping my website fast.

Comment: I think it should go without saying encrypting a value and storing it in cookie is tricky as all ecnryption, but putting something in PHP session and using it is the way to do this. Because if someone can break/steal php session cookie he already broke your authentication!

Comment: well, i'm opposed to store data in cookies, beside session identifier ofcourse, like you said, it can be easily manipulated if not encrypted, although i'm using codeigniter, i still prefer PHP native session utility, about stolen session id concern, i always store users data such as IP and user agent in the session related to the session id, so if a session id from a different IP and user agent combination detected, that session id immediately destroyed, that way, i think PHP native session is more secure than codeigniter session cookie (which also store IP in the cookie which is useless IMO)

Comment: @am05mhz CI also destroys the cookie in the same condition.

Comment: @lighta the difference is, with cookie, you can manipulate it all, get the session id, set the ip to match current ip, and also the user agent, with php session, attackers only can manipulate their session id, because its the only data available to them, ofcourse this is assuming your cookie data is not replicated in your server

Comment: @am05mhz There is the thing, you can't manipulate the data too, if you do so, CI Session will know that and will delete it. That's why i asked this question, i do not see the security risk.

Comment: no, CI session, **if there is no replication data on the server side and without encryption**, will not now if it has been edited if all the conditions checked by CI the same as the environment the attacker use, therefore, CI will let it pass

Comment: @lighta let say, assuming CI only use IP and user agent (haven't see the code inside), user A has IP 1.2.3.4 and use chrome, therefore CI store its data as `session_id=xyz;ip=1.2.3.4;browser=chrome`, then user B found that cookie, user B has IP 4.3.2.1 and use firefox, user B then change his cookie to `session_id=xyz;ip=4.3.2.1;browser=firefox`, then CI check the cookie with the user environment, it would match, CI would not know if the cookie have been altered, unless, there is more data CI check, which i believe there is none of it, since cookie has size limit

Comment: @am05mhz See my edit. Thanks by the way for your answers :)

Comment: @lighta in that case, CI session is the same as PHP session (if you handle it properly), i see no objection if there is a hash stored in server side to be compared with the cookie, since you must handle PHP session on your own, or create a lib for that, then CI session is more preferred, but then again, you have to be careful with cookie size.

Comment: What about cookie size ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering just the part about "So tell me please, the relative risk in addition to PHP native session for this case."

A good way to steal the session is to get on someone's computer and copy the cookie and send to yourself(no matter if using database table or not!!!!!) then re-use that cookie on another computer.  Of course, EVERY single web application is open to this attack.

While I like the idea by @am05mhz in reality if you are in a corporation, you may show up as the same exact ip address to the webserver and I still have successfully stolen a copy of the users session and can now masquerade as him.....in my opinion, the whole ip thing is not worth it the more I think about it though I found the idea interesting.

In other server side session based apps, this can be possible as well by taking the cookie that maps to the server side session(or the jsessionid if in java and cookies are turned off)....after all there is always some state on the web browser mapping you back the server side session.

At any rate, if you are using https and you are using the correct secureOnly flags in your cookies or http headers(can't remember the exact flags), you are about as secure as you are going to get.

The only thing you really need to worry about if you send your entire session client side is really never putting critical data in it like passwords or credit card numbers, etc. etc.

We also timeout the users on our websites after 20 minutes and erase the cookie as a security measure.

I don't know if helps anyone but I thought I would post it.

EDIT: Revisiting the ip thing. For http, the ip thing works very well so anyone outside your corporation can't steal your session but anyone inside your corporation can still steal your session. (ie. sending your session cookie if logged in over http is very susceptible whether using database session storage or not).

Dean

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly suggest to store sessions in a database because it's more secured in that way, to store sessions, you must first create a database table for this purpose.

For more details see [Saving Session Data to a Database](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) section on the documentation. Also you can encrypt cookies. Hera is another answer about [CodeIgniter session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005552/codeigniter-sessions-vs-php-sessions) and it doesn't make your site slow as you mentioned in your comment and remember if you save non-encrypted session data in user's computer then it's really not a very good idea and I suggest you not to do it.

Comment: There are already 3K sql requests by hours. And if i use session database a hacker can also stole the cookie who contain the key. so it's the same problem for both.

Answer (score -1):

CI logon cookies implement persistent logon, a Remember me feature, where value is persisted in database and set in cookie and returned to user. If both values match user is authenticated. If you do not use this feature, there is no difference you should use PHP session to store authentication/authorization related data. You might also enable httpOnly option to your session cookies.