# CodeIgniter deleting my cookies

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I created a cookie outside of CodeIgniter's `ci_session` but every time the CodeIgniter session expires, it deletes my cookie as well. Is there anyway to NOT destroy MY cookie?

I'm a beginner with CodeIgniter and the session class reference doesn't answer my question.

`setcookie( $name , $value , $expire );`

I'm setting it with a different expiration value but still expires the same as CodeIgniter's `ci_session`.

The same happens when I use `$_SESSION`.

Comment: What is the value of `$expire`? I'm thinking it's not very long and just happens to have died when you look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using cookies and sessions with CodeIgniter, I used filesystem functions of PHP. This way, the "cookies and sessions" I created won't expire the same as (or get deleted by) CodeIgniter.

Comment: A session is meant to expire. And I guess doing a `setcookie("foo","bar",time()+3600*24*365)` would be enough "not to expire"

Comment: I know that session is meant to expire but being deleted by CodeIgniter even though it's not set inside ci_session is not normal.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter does not use native sessions, although you can choose to use native sessions but the way codeigniter has implemented the common session usage is much better. Kindly check this post for more information [CodeIgniter sessions vs PHP sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005552/codeigniter-sessions-vs-php-sessions)

Secondly make sure you have configured the sessions correctly. As I have been facing the same problem when I was working on a job portal developed using codeigniter. I recommend that you go through the documentation once again here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html and re-check the configuration of your application.