# Delete Cookie codeigniter ci_session

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I want to delete the cookie ci_session

Is it possible?

If the user select don't want cookies, I delete the cookie with delete_cookie('ci_session'), but if the user refreshes the page, the cookie ci_session is generated.

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930774/codeigniter-deleting-my-cookies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter deleting my cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930774/codeigniter-deleting-my-cookies)

Answer (score 1):

This helper function gives you friendlier syntax to get browser cookies. Refer to the [Input Library](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) for detailed description of its use, as this function acts very similarly to `CI_Input::cookie()`, except it will also prepend the `$config['cookie_prefix']` that you might’ve set in your `application/config/config.php` file.

```
delete_cookie($name[, $domain = ''[, $path = '/'[, $prefix = '']]]);
```

[Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html?highlight=delete_cookie#delete_cookie)

And see this : [How to delete cookie on codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565336/how-to-delete-cookie-on-codeigniter)