# codeigniter session is not working in IE but all other browsers are working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i set a session data to userdata and redirect to a page. but session data is not saved in IE but chrome, firefox and opera is working

```
public function access_granted(){
     $user_session_data = array(
                                 'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                                 'is_user_logged_in' => 1
                               );

            $this->session->set_userdata(array("user" => $user_session_data));
            $this->session->set_flashdata('successed', 'You Logged in Successedfully');
            redirect('index');
    }
```

Comment: [Did you tried that?](https://www.google.fr/search?q=ie+codeigniter+session)

Comment: yes i did. and also i tried without redirecting and tried to load the page 
$this->load->view('index'); 
and it works. i can't understand what is going on

Comment: What is your cookie name? Try removing the underscore from it if it has one. Also what versions of IE?

Comment: i just use codeigniter session library. i didn't save them as cookies.
i'm using IE 8 
and i just simply try to set a session user data and read that session from another page. redirect is not working.

Comment: The `sess_cookie_name` is defined on the config.php file of your codeingniter.

Comment: $config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';

Comment: Try removing the underbar... I'm not sure if it will change anything for IE8, but it was a problem on earlier versions of IE.

Comment: Also recommend you to read the comments of the following question http://stackoverflow.com/a/2006044/342740 where they comment about when using the underscore it fails on IE while when removing it everything works fine.

Comment: i tried removing the underscore. still the problem is there. other all browsers working. :(

Comment: Is the browser in compatibility mode? Could be IE8's privacy settings even.

Comment: Is the date/time settings on you computer are accurate? Some browsers expire the session as soon as it sets if you have the wrong date/time on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

use this header in the controller constructor

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

If this doesn't work better to use the native session than the CI session..

Answer (score 0):

I found this article, and it appears to solve the problem for me, but I want to test more before I confirm. In the mean time, you can try this?

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/211955/#982986

Also as mentioned in the comments of your answer, remove the underscore "_" in the cookie name in config.php, if it exists.

Regards,

Kobus